# LLVM: member alignment from data-layout

Tags: struct, types, padding, llvm-ir

I need to understand how to get member alignment in non-packed literal structures from the data layout.

As specified [here](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#t-struct), It's possible to get this info.

For example, I have this piece of code:

```
; ModuleID = 'fy4vsjaw.hjq.cpp'
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-pc-linux"

%struct.S = type { i8, i64 }  

; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define { i8, i64 } @foo() #0 !dbg !4 {
```

in the line `%struct.S = type { i8, i64 }` , what is the padding between two members here?

I'd expect 32 or 64 bits, but I'd like to be sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's indeed written in the data layout. Such as specified in the [data layout spec](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#data-layout), this part `i64:64` of the layout indicates that int64 are 64 bits aligned.

In the struct `%struct.S = type { i8, i64 }`, there is therefore a 7 byte padding between the two fields.

Programmatically, it's possible to get offset of member by index:

```
uint64_t GetOffset(llvm::Module* mod, llvm::StructType* st, uint32_t int index) {
    return mod->getDataLayout()->getStructLayout(st)->getElementOffset(index);
}
```